# Record UI elements for TestFX

Tags: javafx, desktop-application, ui-automation, testfx

There is an existing JavaFX based application, which I should write automated tests for. I just started to use TestFX(version 4.0.13-alpha) and looking for advice, how to record and identify UI objects of application.
I tried following code to initialize a button, but it couldn't be clicked.

```
Button button = new Button("click me!");
```

I found [these](https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool) GUI inspect tools, but not sure, which one could works with TestFX.

Answer (score 3):

There is a really good documentation about TestFX queries which can be found on github ([here](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/wiki/Queries)). I would use the `lookup(<label/buttontext>)` version if it's not possible to define IDs on the components.

Comment: I see, but it is not possible in case of black box testing.

Comment: that doesn't mean that you can't use the `lookup` queries, or does it?

Comment: As I see, yes. As a simple example, you can't use it also with calculator application.